# Out of memory exception on Retrofit & Font asset not found

Tags: java, android, service, fonts, retrofit2

I'm trying to fetch data from json service using Retrofit library. It was running fine when I was testing it on Samsung Galaxy S6. But When I tried to run it on Samsung Galaxy S4. It gave me **out of memory exception** and font not found in assets. Even I've font asset in fonts directory.

**Here are my logs:**

```
10-24 22:42:36.546 827-3374/com.mianasad.deen D/TAG: request
                                                     Sending request http://mianasad.com/***/getFatwasbyCategory.php?keyword=%D8%AD%D8%AC on null
10-24 22:42:38.108 827-3374/com.mianasad.deen D/TAG: response
                                                     Received response for http://mianasad.com/***/getFatwasbyCategory.php?keyword=%D8%AD%D8%AC in 1044.1ms
                                                     Date: Tue, 24 Oct 2017 17:42:06 GMT
                                                     Server: Apache
                                                     X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31
                                                     Vary: Accept-Encoding
                                                     Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

                                                     {"response":[{"Fatwa":"\u0635\u0627\u062d\u0628\u0650 \u062d\u062b\u06cc\u062a \u06a9\u0648 \u067e\u06c1\u0644\u06d2 \u062d\u062c \u06a9\u0631\u0646\u0627 \u0686\u0627\u06c1\u06cc\u06d2 \u06cc\u0627 \u0639\u0645\u0631\u06c1\u061f","Id":"158","Answer":"\u0639\u0645\u0631\u06c1 \u06a9\u0631\u0646\u06d2 \u0633\u06d2 \u062d\u062c \u0641\u0631\u0636 \u0646\u06c1\u06cc\u06ba \u06c1\u0648\u062a\u0627\u060c \u062d\u062c \u0635\u0627\u062d\u0628 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0637\u0627\u0639\u062a \u0634\u062e\u0635 \u067e\u0631 \u0641\u0631\u0636 \u06c1\u0648\u062a\u0627 \u06c1\u06d2\u06d4 \u062c\u0648 \u0627\u0633\u062a\u0637\u0627\u0639\u062a \u0631\u06a9\u06be\u062a\u0627 \u06c1\u06d2\u060c \u062d\u062c \u06a9\u0631\u06d2 \u0627\u0648\u0631 \u0648\u06c1\u0627\u06ba \u062c\u0627 \u06a9\u0631 \u062c\u062a\u0646\u06d2 \u0639\u0645\u0631\u06d2 \u06a9\u0631 \u0633\u06a9\u062a\u06d2 \u06c1\u06cc\u06ba \u0628\u06d2 \u0634\u06a9 \u06a9\u0631\u06cc\u06ba\u060c \u06a9\u0648\u0626\u06cc \u067e\u0627\u0628\u0646\u062f\u06cc \u0646\u06c1\u06cc\u06ba \u06c1\u06d2\u06d4 \u0639\u0645\u0631\u06c1 \u06a9\u0631\u0646\u06d2 \u06a9\u0627 \u0648\u0642\u062a \u067e\u06c1\u0644\u06d2 \u0645\u06cc\u0633\u0631 \u06c1\u0648 \u062a\u0648 \u067e\u06c1\u0644\u06d2 \u0628\u06be\u06cc \u06a9\u0631 \u0633\u06a9\u062a\u06d2 \u06c1\u06cc\u06ba\u06d4","Mufti":"\u0639\u0628\u062f\u0627\u0644\u0642\u06cc\u0648\u0645 \u06c1\u0632\u0627\u0631\u0648\u06cc"},{"Fatwa":"\u06a9\u06cc\u0627 \u0633\u0639\u0648\u062f\u06cc \u062d\u06a9\u0648\u0645\u062a \u06a9\u06cc \u0637\u0631\u0641 \u0633\u06d2 \u0644\u0648\u06af\u0648\u06ba \u067e\u0631 \u0627\u062f\u0627\u0626\u06cc\u06af\u06cc \u062d\u062c \u0633\u06d2 \u0631\u0648\u06a9\u0646\u06d2 \u06a9\u06d2 \u0644\u06cc\u06d2 \u067e\u0627\u0628\u0646\u062f\u06cc\u0627\u06ba \u0644\u06af\u0627\u0646\u0627 \u062c\u0627\u0626\u0632 \u06c1\u06d2\u061f","Id":"187","Answer":"\u062c\u0648\u06ba \u062c\u0648\u06ba \u0622\u0628\u0627\u062f\u06cc \u0628\u0691\u06be\u062a\u06cc \u062c\u0627 \u0631\u06c1\u06cc \u06c1\u06d2 \u062a\u0648\u06ba \u062a\u0648\u06ba \u0645\u0633\u0627\u0626\u0644 \u0645\u06cc\u06ba \u0628\u06be\u06cc \u0627\u0636\u0627\u0641\u06c1 \u06c1\u0648\u062a\u0627 \u062c\u0627 \u0631\u06c1\u0627 \u06c1\u06d2\u060c \u0627\u0633 \u0644\u06cc\u06d2 \u0627\u06af\u0631 \u0633\u0639\u0648\u062f\u06cc \u062d\u06a9\u0648\u0645\u062a \u0628\u0627\u0631 \u0628\u0627\u0631 \u062d\u062c \u06a9\u0631\u0646\u06d2 \u067e\u0631 \u067e\u0627\u0628\u0646\u062f\u06cc \u0644\u06af\u0627\u0626\u06d2 \u062a\u0627\u06a9\u06c1 \u0633\u0628 \u06a9\u0648 \u0645\u0648\u0642\u0639 \u0645\u0644\u06d2 \u06cc\u0627 \u0645\u062e\u062a\u0644\u0641 \u0645\u0644\u06a9\u0648\u06ba \u06a9\u06d2 \u0644\u06cc\u06d2 \u0622\u0628\u0627\u062f\u06cc \u06a9\u06d2 \u0645\u0637\u0627\u0628\u0642 \u0645\u062e\u062a\u0644\u0641 \u06a9\u0648\u0679\u06d2 \u0631\u06a9\u06be \u062f\u06d2 \u062a\u0648 \u0627\u0633 \u0637\u0631\u062d \u06a9\u06cc \u067e\u0627\u0628\u0646\u062f\u06cc\u0627\u06ba \u0644\u06af\u0627\u0626\u06cc \u062c\u0627 \u0633\u06a9\u062a\u06cc \u06c1\u06cc\u06ba\u06d4 \u062c\u0627\u0626\u0632 \u06c1\u06d2 \u06a9\u06cc\u0648\u0646\u06a9\u06c1 \u0627\u0646\u062a\u0638\u0627\u0645\u0627\u062a \u06a9\u06d2 \u0645\u0637\u0627\u0628\u0642 \u06c1\u06cc \u0644\u0648\u06af \u0641\u0631\u06cc\u0636\u06c1 \u062d\u062c \u0627\u062f\u0627 \u06a9\u0631 \u0633\u06a9\u06cc\u06ba \u06af\u06d2","Mufti":"\u0639\u0628\u062f\u0627\u0644\u0642\u06cc\u0648\u0645 \u06c1\u0632\u0627\u0631\u0648\u06cc"},{"Fatwa":"\u062d\u062c \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0627\u0648\u0631 \u062d\u062c \u062a\u0645\u062a\u0639 \u06a9\u06d2 \u0628\u0627\u0631\u06d2 \u0645\u06cc\u06ba\u200c \u0628\u062a\u0627\u0626\u06cc\u06ba\u061f","Id":"195","Answer":"\u062d\u062c \u0642\u0631\u0627\u0646 \u0633\u06d2 \u0645\u0631\u0627\u062f \u062d\u062c
10-24 22:42:38.208 827-827/com.mianasad.deen E/Total Items Received:: 45
10-24 22:42:54.364 827-827/com.mianasad.deen E/filemap: mmap(0,20787696) failed: Out of memory
10-24 22:42:54.364 827-827/com.mianasad.deen W/asset: create map from entry failed
10-24 22:42:54.404 827-827/com.mianasad.deen D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-24 22:42:54.444 827-834/com.mianasad.deen W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.171ms
10-24 22:42:54.454 827-827/com.mianasad.deen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.mianasad.deen, PID: 827
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/urdu.ttf
                                                                   at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:272)
                                                                   at com.mianasad.deen.FatwaAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FatwaAdapter.java:41)
                                                                   at com.mianasad.deen.FatwaAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(FatwaAdapter.java:29)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6367)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5555)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3025)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1420)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:482)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:874)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18596)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:289
```

Comment: I believe your problem with **`OOM`** doesn't link with `Retrofit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear in the log.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/urdu.ttf

You are calling an Asset in your project called `urdu.ttf` (which is a font asset) but you didn't add it under `/assets` folder

Comment: I copied it in assets folder and it is completely working fine on my other device. But on some devices it is not working.